# Stylelint: background-size after background-position in background shortcut rule

Tags: stylelint

According to MDN:

> The `<bg-size>` value may only be included immediately after `<position>`, separated with the '/' character, like this: "center/80%".

Is there any way to check this rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to check the *validity* of your CSS code against the specifications, which is best done with a validator like [CSSTree](https://github.com/csstree/validator).

You can use the [stylelint-csstree-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-csstree-validator) stylelint plugin to run this validator within stylelint.

(You can [test the validator online](https://csstree.github.io/docs/validator.html) and it will flag a misformed `background` value, including a misplaced `<bg-size>`.)